# Как в CSS сделать фон со стрелкой-разделителем

Tags: css

Интересует, как средствами CSS можно сделать такой фон:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует конкретно стрелка вправо, между заголовком "задать вопрос специалисту" и "ваше имя".

**Почему это не дубликат**
В указанном вопросе автор спрашивает, как сделать полупрозрачной стрелку вниз (указательную стрелку, как у цитат). У меня вопрос о том, как сделать стрелку на фоне. По моему, общего тут ничего нет.
Вопрос на ответ я получил.

Comment: Попробуйте вот этот тул: http://www.cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
.content .block1 {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
.content .block2:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 75px solid transparent;
  border-left: 75px solid #ff0;
  border-bottom: 75px solid transparent;
}
.content .block2 {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 0 70%;
  background-color: #ffa500;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

[Подробнее про геометрические фигуры на CSS](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/)
Про псевдоэлементы [:before](http://htmlbook.ru/css/before), [:after](http://htmlbook.ru/css/after)

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)